# Google Actions trigger by physical button

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Is it currently possible to trigger a google action (intent) command through a physical button, rather than voice?

Instead of Hey Google, (custom command for custom action),

A button is pressed and the text command is sent to the google home triggering the intent.

I'm attempting to do this through Raspberry Pi 3 (Android Things) and Actions Console.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably want to look into the [Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/).

Comment: Thank you! It looks like this might set me in the right direction. I'll dive into it if you are unsure but do you know if the speaker of a google home can still be utilized rather than connecting the pi to a speaker?

Comment: No, there's no direct way to send audio to a Home.